# Problem with auto-generated primary_key using jpa on DerbyDB

Tags: jpa, primary-key, generator, derby

I have jpa annotated entity class like:

```
@Configurable
@Entity
@Table(name="PLAYERS")
public class Player
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @PersistenceContext
        public transient EntityManager entityManager;

    ...
}
```

This has worked fine until I decided to create table with backuped yaml data using syntax like:

```
createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO PLAYERS ...")
```

After successful creation when I try to create an entity with:

```
Player player = new Player();
player.setName("new player");
player.persist();
```

i got error:

```
SQL Error: -1, SQLState: 23505
```

related to the duplication of primary_keys, because id generated for new entity = 1 (the same as row retrived from backuped data). Of course I can retrive data from backup file by using jpa/java syntax but in this case I have no control over primary keys of inserted data etc. 
How to solve this problem ? Is there any way to update id_generator after the insertion of backuped data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you inserted data manually, you need to alter the table to change the start value of the identity column:

```
ALTER TABLE PLAYERS ALTER COLUMN ID RESTART WITH 1234;
```

Where 1234 is the max id of your backup data.

More details in the documentation of the [ALTER TABLE statement](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html):

> RESTART WITH integer-constant
>   specifies the next value to be
>   generated for the identity column.
>   RESTART WITH is useful for a table
>   that has an identity column that was
>   defined as GENERATED BY DEFAULT and
>   that has a unique key defined on that
>   identity column. Because GENERATED BY
>   DEFAULT allows both manual inserts and
>   system generated values, it is
>   possible that manually inserted values
>   can conflict with system generated
>   values. To work around such conflicts,
>   use the RESTART WITH syntax to specify
>   the next value that will be generated
>   for the identity column. Consider the
>   following example, which involves a
>   combination of automatically generated
>   data and manually inserted data:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE tauto(i INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, k INT)
> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tautoInd ON tauto(i)
> INSERT INTO tauto(k) values 1,2
> ```
>
> The system will automatically generate
>   values for the identity column.?? But
>   now you need to manually insert some
>   data into the identity column:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO tauto VALUES (3,3)
> INSERT INTO tauto VALUES (4,4)
> INSERT INTO tauto VALUES (5,5)
> ```
>
> The identity column has used values 1
>   through 5 at this point.?? If you now
>   want the system to generate a value,
>   the system will generate a 3, which
>   will result in a unique key exception
>   because the value 3 has already been
>   manually inserted.????To compensate
>   for the manual inserts, issue an ALTER
>   TABLE statement for the identity
>   column with RESTART WITH 6:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE tauto ALTER COLUMN i RESTART WITH 6
> ```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, works as desired. Another possible solution that I discovered is : to modify field AUTOINCREMENTVALUE within SYS.SYSCOLUMNS table, that  DerbyDb uses to store last generated value for primary_key but because this is system table, admin privileges are required. So this is more troublesome solution.

Comment: @user85005: Yes, that would work too (but will require more privileges as you noticed). Actually, the alter will result in a modification of the system tables. It's just more handy to use the alter IMO.